# How do I export a DataTable and text to PDF?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Dim dt As DataTable
dt=some query
Dim GridView1 As New GridView()
GridView1.AllowPaging = False
GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=DataTable.pdf")
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Dim sw As New StringWriter()
Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
pdfDoc.Open()
htmlparser.Parse(sr)
pdfDoc.Close()
Response.Write(pdfDoc)
Response.End()
```

I need to export text along with a `DataTable` to PDF. I get `GridView1.Columns.Count = 0` after `DataBind()`. In `dt` there are columns, but after `DataBind()`, `Columns.Count` returns 0.
dt=some query.but shows count=0

Comment: So basically your issue has nothing to do with PDF creation but is actually about the gridview not being initialized with your datatable items?

Comment: try remove this `GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False` with it, the gridview can create the columns based on the `dt`

Comment: Yes i removed it.but still shows count=0 @Keith Mifsud

Comment: Datatable export to pdf,but i need some text to be displayed in that pdf also @grek40